# Flutter offline map view - how to create Linker Address Map(.map) file for offline purpose?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, openstreetmap, mapsforge

I want to show the map in offline mode. the package [mapsforge_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/mapsforge_flutter) is best for this purpose. We can download the offline map data from [here](https://download.mapsforge.org/) to use it with the mapsforge_flutter package, but the problem is that the map data of some countries is too large. I want to use an Indian map, you can find it [here](https://download.mapsforge.org/maps/v5/asia/) and its size is 1.2GB. the project was unable to load the asset because of its size. is there any way to create a custom .map file from the map(Google Map, OpenStreetMap, etc.)

Comment: I'm not sure about OpenStreetMap, but for Google Maps, [3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services. (b) No Caching.](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms#:~:text=3.2.3%C2%A0Restrictions%20Against%20Misusing%20the%20Services.) says that: "Customer will not cache Google Maps Content except as expressly permitted under the Maps Service Specific Terms." But I'm not a lawyer, so I'd suggest that you consult one.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. However, I've chosen not to employ Google Maps due to its constraints, especially in regard to caching permissions.

Comment: You can create your own mapsforge *.map file based on OSM using https://extract.bbbike.org/